# How stop affecting the CSS of other content to our site?

Tags: java, jquery, css, html

In my web page I required to fetch email and display content of the email. it's done success fully now only one issue is that when the content of the email is load in my page at that time the CSS of that mail is affect to my page and change the colors of link and so many thing.
I have wrote following code

```
<div class="ticket-reply-content"> <!-- division to print the messages -->
    ${replies.message_modify}<!--this will load content dynamically -->
</div>
```

Please give me some solution or tag.

Comment: If the loaded elements have inline styles, you could either remove their `style` attribute/value by JavaScript, or override the rulesets within your stylesheet by using `!important` keyword.

Comment: *CSS of that mail* - does the email contains css in a `<style>` tag??

Comment: @HashemQolami How will inline styles affect other elements in the page?

Comment: @TJ In terms of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), inline styles has a higher specificity value than `#id`, `.class`, `element` selectors. Hence it would override the declarations defined within the stylesheet not for the entire of the page, but for the particular section they are appended.

Comment: @HashemQolami So? the issue as far as i understand is the styles in loaded content affecting other parts of the site... inline styles only affect the element it's applied to as far as i know.

Comment: @TJ yes email contains the <style> tag so it's affect

Comment: @UdayA.Navapara Only solution i can think of is somehow loading the content inside an `<iframe>`...

Comment: i have try that <iframe> is load successfully but content is not load in that

Answer (score 0):

**No** you can't disable css to particular div.

If your `div` selector matches then a rule will apply until overridden by a rule (which sets the same property) further down the cascade. You can use `!important` to override rules.

You can either change your div's class or id to stop them matching the elements you don't want them to match, or you can override all your rules in that section.

### Update

I believe you should load content of Email in `Iframe`. This way css of Mail will not effect other content of web page.

Comment: There is not issue on class or id it's css directly affect to the elements

Comment: Which element? @UdayA.Navapara. `<div>`??

Comment: can you say hot to put content in iframe? i think iframe is used to load other page by src

Comment: You can place Email content in another page and simply can give url of that page to iframe

Comment: in my case it is not possible because the data come from database and it's put in loop

Answer (score 0):

try to change it like this :
for example if you have like this code :

```
.yourclass{
```

}

change it to specific condition:

```
.parent_element .yourclass
  {

  }
```

or try to use !important

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of preventing the style tag embedded in the message from leaking out

Answer (score 0):

don't use a regular name of class in your code for example don't use header footer content, you can concatenate all the class name with the name of your website to ensure don't have a confusion of classes

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex and localize every one of the selectors in the embedded style tag to only the area where you would like the styles to apply.

ie. `.someclass td` should become `.ticket-reply-content .someclass td` if you only want the styles to apply to the div you have shown.

You should be able to use the regex: `/(.*{)/g` to match any selector and the opening bracket for its declaration.

In Javascript, you would have to do it after you have already loaded the element into the page:

```
$(function() {
    // select each of the style elements
    $('.ticket-reply-content style').each(function(styleElement) {
        // get the css styles from the element
        var oldStyles = styleElement.html();
        // prepend each selector with a class to localize it
        var newStyles = oldStyles.replace(/(.*{)/g, function(match, p1) {
            return '.ticket-reply-content ' + p1;
        });
        // replace the css content
        styleElement.html(newStyles);
    }); 
});
```

You should be able to find the style element inside of `replies.message_modify` and use a similar approach from the java backend